# Is there a property similar to isContentEditable for autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I'm trying to determine if a form input text box is "autocomplete disabled". There are basically two scenarios that I can think of:

```
<input type="text" name="n1" id="id1" autocomplete="Off" />
```

and when it's defined in the form itself:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="someurl.com">
    <input type="text" name="n1" id="id1" />
</form>
```

Some time ago I needed to find out if an element is `content editable` and I found out about a single property `isContentEditable` that was able to resolve it. So I'm curious if there's a similar way to determine if an input text box is "autocomplete disabled"?

PS1. I need this for the content script in the Google Chrome extension.

PS2. I'm using "raw" JavaScript/DOM, so JQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

Simples: use the autocomplete property for input(text) and forms to check/set the autocomplete value.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="n1" id="id1" autocomplete="Off" />

<script>
var check = document.getElementById("id1").autocomplete;

if (check.toLowerCase() == "off")
{
 // do something here when autocomplete is off
}
</script>
```

Comment: `autocomplete` is not just a boolean property, you know.

Comment: @c00000fd, I don't understand, autocomplete can only be "on" or "off". What am I missing?

Comment: It can be set to any string value, including "off", "OFF", "Off", etc. But I'm not sure what exactly your `check` was supposed to be used for. Anyway, I can do all this myself. I was hoping to find a boolean property like `isContentEditable` but for autocomplete.

Comment: Sorry, just edited my answer a bit, it should return "off" not 0. It doesn't matter whether its "Off", "OFF", or "off". It still returns "off" which you can then use in an if statement (if (check == "off")).

Comment: Please check your statements before posting. The last one is again not true. In either case, I know all this. Thanks for trying to help...

Comment: Also, since the default is "on", you wouldn't need to check against this.

Comment: Well I tested with "off", "OFF" and "oFF". All gave the same result. Anywho, no problem!

Comment: ;) OK, it's a third edit though. And what about when it's defined in the form itself. It all requires more code. Let me repeat for the 3rd time, I know all this. I'm looking for a simple boolean property to do all this.